# Why does re-using an iterator variable in nested loops not cause issues in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, cfml

I've been looking at some old code at work and I've found several instances of nested loops in which the variable used for iterating over an object is re-assigned within the inner loop but it does not cause issues. For instance given the following `example.cfm`:

```
<cfscript>

    // Get every second value in an array of arrays
    function contrivedExampleFunction(required array data) {
        var filtered = [];

        for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(arguments.data); i++) {
            var inner = arguments.data[i];

            for (i = 1; i lte arrayLen(inner); i++) {
                if (i eq 2) {
                    arrayAppend(filtered, inner);
                }
            }
        }

        return filtered;
    }

    data = [
        [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]
    ];

    // Expected (working function): [2, 5, 8]
    // Expected (short-circuiting): [2]
    // Actual result: [1, 2, 3]
    writeDump( contrivedExampleFunction(data) );

</cfscript>
```

I would expect the inner `i` declaration to re-assign the outer `i` and cause the function to 'short-circuit', especially as `i` *isn't even scoped*. However the function will return an unpredictable result. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not desk-checking the code properly. It's wrong, but it works as expected.

```
The outer loop will loop i from 1-3
    First iteration i=1
    inner = data[1] => [1,2,3]
    The inner loop will loop i from 1-3
        First iteration i=1
            nothing to do
        Second iteration i=2
            append inner to filtered => [1,2,3]
        Third iteration i=3
            nothing to do
    end inner loop
    i=3, which meets the exit condition of the outer loop
end of outer loop

filtered = [1,2,3]
```

I think you are misreading this line of code:

```
arrayAppend(filtered, inner);
```

You're reading it as:

```
arrayAppend(filtered, inner[i]);
```

But it doesn't say that.

Make sense?

Comment: Good spot! I have found several instances in a codebase whereby an inner loop is re-assigning the outer iteration variable (neither scoped) which is distressing me somewhat. I guess now I have a good example of why *not* to ever do this (other than it being crazy) rather than the example of weird CF behaviour I thought I had.

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  Lines like writeoutput("before the inner loop i is #i#") are quite handy.